# Linking two or more different programming languages

Tags: optimization, simulation, linking

I would like to ask how optimizer software written in C/C++ can be linked to simulator software written in FORTRAN or any other language. I have copied the section of journal article of **Singh and Chakrabarty (2011)**.

> In the present study, MODFLOW 2000 and MT3DMS 5.0 are
>   linked as independent modules with the optimization code.
>   Modifications are made to the codes of the simulators in such a
>   way that they can be run through input files, and both of them
>   are then compiled. One of the files required to run MODFLOW
>   2000 is prepared by the optimization algorithm. This file contains
>   the latest values of the decision variables. The NSGA II separately
>   calls both MODFLOW 2000 and MT3DMS 5.0 in their compiled
>   forms as independent modules. MODFLOW 2000 uses the file
>   prepared by NSGA II to calculate hydraulic head and prepare
>   an output file containing these values. Similarly, MT3DMS 5.0 calculates
>   contaminant concentrations at selected locations and produces
>   an output file containing the concentration values. The output
>   files produced by the simulators are used by NSGA II as input files
>   to produce updated values of the decision variables. The optimization
>   problem, thus, runs until convergence. Obviously, ***writing of
>   interface programs for linking codes written in different languages
>   is altogether eliminated in this technique of linking***.

I believe from here I can move forward with my research.
Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 16):

Linking code (using the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29), e.g. `ld` often started by `gcc` or `gfortran` compilation commands) written in two different languages is implementation specific. It is often called [foreign function interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface). It depends upon [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) specific to the implementations.

On Linux, with code compiled by `gfortran` and `gcc` (both from the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler) is quite easy (in particular because both share a common middle-end and back-end layers of the Gnu Compiler Collection). The `gfortran` documentation has a chapter about [mixed language programming](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Mixed-Language-Programming.html)

BTW, you can make two [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) (e.g. running two different -or the same- programs, perhaps coded in two different languages) communicate using [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication); this is provided by the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) so is OS specific. On Linux and POSIX you could use [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s, [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)-s, in particular [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) ones (and [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) them appropriately in some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)), shared memory (see [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) & [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) for synchronization with semaphores), etc. Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). You might be interested by [Remote Procedure Calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) (e.g. [JSON-RPC](http://jsonrpc.org/), ....), [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface), etc...

PS. Don't call IPC linking. When talking about software, *linking* means using the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) (e.g. to merge & mix code from various [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) and [libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29) into a *single* [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable)).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will try from here and see how it goes.

Comment: I think, the actual keyword to mention would be "ISO_C_BINDING". The `gfortran` documentation that you've linked includes that, but I think that it's worth mentioning that there is a part of the fortran language specifically designed for linking with C code.

Comment: Yes, for Fortran 2006 code (not for Fortran77, and perhaps not even Fortran90)

Comment: For completeness you may also be interested in `Marshalling` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29

Answer (score 9):

*I think* all they're saying here is that there are two components (one containing MODFLOW 2000 and MT3DMS 5.0, and the other containing NGSA II, with the two components being written in different languages) which simply use files as their interprocess communication (IPC) mechanism - hence the two components are *logically* linked while not being linked as in the "linker" step of a traditional compiler-linker chain.

However, this is not an innovative technique in any way, so either I've misinterpreted things or the authors are spinning things a little bit too much in the quote you've emphasised.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I think this should give a way forward to get started how I can link two languages together.

Comment: @Surajit I suggest you avoid the word `link` because that has specific meaning in regards to languages and compilers. `communicate` is less ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are saying each of the simulator programs is a separate executable, and you run it by 1) writing a file for it to input, 2) spawning a process to run it and waiting for it to complete, and 3) reading its result file.
As they say, in this way the various modules can be written in any language, it doesn't matter what languages.

The problem with this approach is performance.
If it takes longer to execute than you want to wait, chances are you will find, if you use [*this technique*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771), that a quite large fraction of time is spent in each of the three steps - writing, spawning, and reading.
If so, that implies the execution time could be reduced by a big factor.

Compilers like `gcc` and `gfortran` play together nicely, as @Basile points out.
If the various tools can be compiled and linked together into a single executable, and communicate directly through in-memory data passing, eliminating the need for file formatting and parsing, and eliminating the need for process startup, you may find it a big speedup.
Possibly one or two orders of magnitude.